# How do I view Mystery Files?

Tags: 13-sentinels-aegis-rim

At the end of a prologue in *13 Sentinels: Aegis Rim*, the results screen says I've obtained Mystery Files. I checked the menu for a way to read them, but the only choices I see are Save, Load, Title Screen, Manual, and Options.

How do I view the Mystery Files I've obtained?

[image: 13 Sentinels results screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view Mystery Files and Event Archives by opening the Options menu during a Remembrance section. Alternatively, completing the tutorial chapter *Beginning of the End* will unlock Analysis mode on the main menu which will also let you review Mystery Files.